# How to build Urdu stemming library in PHP?

Tags: php, api

There are lot of stemming libraries but they are in other languages but I need an API or library or algorithm that will be use for stemming Urdu words. I want to find the root of a word like in English e.g.

> sadness => sad

Comment: this may work for you but i guess it needs customization for urdu language  support http://phpmorphy.sourceforge.net/dokuwiki/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple libraries and extensions available for this tasks.

**Extensions**

Stem

- https://pecl.php.net/package/stem
- http://snowball.tartarus.org/ ([DEMO](http://snowball.tartarus.org/demo.php))

php-stemmer

https://github.com/hthetiot/php-stemmer

**Libraries**

These Porter-Stemmer libs will also do the job (at least for the english language parts):

- https://github.com/andyceo/PHP-Porter-Stemmer
- http://www.chuggnutt.com/stemmer

PHP Morhpy

http://phpmorphy.sourceforge.net/dokuwiki/

--

Urdu is a mixed language. So the "basic" Porter-Stemming will not be enough (and might only be sufficent for the english language parts of Urdu). You will have to model the language rules. The Urdu language is really challenging for NLP, because of the rich morphology.

If you want to implement a rule based stemmer, then take a look at this paper, which explains the algo used: "[Rule Based Stemmer in Urdu](http://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/1310/1310.0581.pdf)" by Vaishali Gupta, Nisheeth Joshi
, Iti Mathur.

Comment: please guide which one of them is easy for me to change according my need ??? @Jens A. Koch

Comment: Give phpmorphy a try.